# Why is android app created in React Native not opening?

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I made a switch to React Native this month from Angular 7. My major attraction to this fascinating framework is the fast interaction of components (powered by babel for jsx) unlike the .ts controlled HTML templates in Angular 7 which sometimes need a refresh to update the GUI. The capability of HTML in js code is the peak of this framework transition.

I hope to find the relevant help I need here.

However, I am battling with the difficulty to create apk file from my React Native project using Android Studio. I succeeded in creating a signed apk which was installed on my Techno W2 device without any error; but the app isn't opening, and has no visible launch icon too. Although it is listed in the installed apps in settings. After installing, the 'open' button is inactive.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated, as I cannot continue my React Native development unless this is resolved. I want to be creating my apk files locally, and not using Expo services which produce huge file sizes.
Note: My React Native Project is generated by 'expo init project-name', then ejected by 'expo eject' in order to regenerate the android & iOS directories.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try `react-native run-android` in the terminal?

Comment: Maybe silly question and I don't know how exactly it works in react native, but do you have Activity with intent-filter that contains action MAIN and category LAUNCHER?

Comment: I did. The terminal works perfectly. Everything OK. I have problem with the generated apk using Android Studio latest version.

Comment: @Matej I do have those in AndroidManifest.xml in 'android/app/SRC/main' dir

Answer (score 0):

To make android apk using a react-native project you need to first bundle your JS and then hit the apk bundling process.

To bundle the app use the following command first in the root directory of your RN project:

`react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform android --dev false --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res/`

Once this process is completed, create a signed apk and you should be able to ru your app successfully.

From learning point of view: I would say NOT TO USE EXPO. As the documentation there is poor and it totally makes things look simple and then you finds yourself in a no mans land when you need to work on complex things using the native dependencies. Learn from the official docs and try to stick to `react-native init`.

Comment: Thank you all for responding. I later got it working. Android Studio works well in signing and creating the apk (CLI method is a no for me). The latest version of Studio comes with apk minify and apk analyze capabilities. I had dropped Expo. The Native way gives lots of control; only that one have to search for more solutions most times.

Comment: Dropping Expo is the smartest thing one can ever do. Its crap and the documentation is way poor than the official RN docs and it sucks the development by restricting the possibilities of debugging and getting to know the real part of mobile.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I do not recommend to use EXPO. Instead of creating project in EXPO use normal method to create project using react-native init YouProject

- [Instructions for create normal project](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

Before run your project make sure all node modules are setup correctly. 
To install node modules run **`npm install --save`**

Run your project using 
**`react-native run-android`** for android 
**`react-native run-ios`** for iOS

Instructions for genarate unsigned APK

1. Make sure you have delete previous build files if you have any.
2. Delete build folder on **YourProject > android > app > build**
3. Run this script command from your terminal in order to generate output apk.

**`mkdir -p android/app/src/main/assets && rm -rf android/app/build && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && cd android && ./gradlew assembleDebug`**

4. Get your output apk from **YourProject > android > app > build > outputs > apk > debug**

To get signed apk use [this instrctions](https://dev.to/zilurrane/generate-release-mode-apk-for-react-native-project-to-publish-on-playstore-5f78)